# What is the use of the type userptr_t in os161?

Tags: c, operating-system, kernel, os161

I'm trying to complete an assignment for an operating systems course, [Here](https://www.ops-class.org/asst/2/).

I had a question from the assignment:

> What is the purpose of userptr_t?

When I searched the source code for `userptr_t`, [Here](https://github.com/ops-class/os161/blob/master/kern/include/types.h#L85), I found this:

```
/*
 * Define userptr_t as a pointer to a one-byte struct, so it won't mix
 * with other pointers.
 */

struct __userptr { char _dummy; };
typedef struct __userptr *userptr_t;
typedef const struct __userptr *const_userptr_t;
```

I can't get to understand completely the use of it, can anyone explain what is the purpose of this type?

It's used here for example in the file `copyinout.c` in the functions `copyin`, `copyout`, `copyinstr`, `copyoutstr` and other functions:

```
#include <types.h>
#include <kern/errno.h>
#include <lib.h>
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <thread.h>
#include <current.h>
#include <vm.h>
#include <copyinout.h>

/*
 * User/kernel memory copying functions.
 *
 * These are arranged to prevent fatal kernel memory faults if invalid
 * addresses are supplied by user-level code. This code is itself
 * machine-independent; it uses the machine-dependent C setjmp/longjmp
 * facility to perform recovery.
 *
 * However, it assumes things about the memory subsystem that may not
 * be true on all platforms.
 *
 * (1) It assumes that user memory is mapped into the current address
 * space while running in the kernel, and can be accessed by just
 * dereferencing a pointer in the ordinary way. (And not, for example,
 * with special instructions or via special segment registers.)
 *
 * (2) It assumes that the user-space region of memory is contiguous
 * and extends from 0 to some virtual address USERSPACETOP, and so if
 * a user process passes a kernel address the logic in copycheck()
 * will trap it.
 *
 * (3) It assumes that access to user memory from the kernel behaves
 * the same way as access to user memory from user space: for
 * instance, that the processor honors read-only bits on memory pages
 * when in kernel mode.
 *
 * (4) It assumes that if a proper user-space address that is valid
 * but not present, or not valid at all, is touched from the kernel,
 * that the correct faults will occur and the VM system will load the
 * necessary pages and whatnot.
 *
 * (5) It assumes that the machine-dependent trap logic provides and
 * honors a tm_badfaultfunc field in the thread_machdep structure.
 * This feature works as follows: if an otherwise fatal fault occurs
 * in kernel mode, and tm_badfaultfunc is set, execution resumes in
 * the function pointed to by tm_badfaultfunc.
 *
 * This code works by setting tm_badfaultfunc and then copying memory
 * in an ordinary fashion. If these five assumptions are satisfied,
 * which is the case for many ordinary CPU types, this code should
 * function correctly. If the assumptions are not satisfied on some
 * platform (for instance, certain old 80386 processors violate
 * assumption 3), this code cannot be used, and cpu- or platform-
 * specific code must be written.
 *
 * To make use of this code, in addition to tm_badfaultfunc the
 * thread_machdep structure should contain a jmp_buf called
 * "tm_copyjmp".
 */

/*
 * Recovery function. If a fatal fault occurs during copyin, copyout,
 * copyinstr, or copyoutstr, execution resumes here. (This behavior is
 * caused by setting t_machdep.tm_badfaultfunc and is implemented in
 * machine-dependent code.)
 *
 * We use the C standard function longjmp() to teleport up the call
 * stack to where setjmp() was called. At that point we return EFAULT.
 */
static
void
copyfail(void)
{
    longjmp(curthread->t_machdep.tm_copyjmp, 1);
}

/*
 * Memory region check function. This checks to make sure the block of
 * user memory provided (an address and a length) falls within the
 * proper userspace region. If it does not, EFAULT is returned.
 *
 * stoplen is set to the actual maximum length that can be copied.
 * This differs from len if and only if the region partially overlaps
 * the kernel.
 *
 * Assumes userspace runs from 0 through USERSPACETOP-1.
 */
static
int
copycheck(const_userptr_t userptr, size_t len, size_t *stoplen)
{
    vaddr_t bot, top;

    *stoplen = len;

    bot = (vaddr_t) userptr;
    top = bot+len-1;

    if (top < bot) {
        /* addresses wrapped around */
        return EFAULT;
    }

    if (bot >= USERSPACETOP) {
        /* region is within the kernel */
        return EFAULT;
    }

    if (top >= USERSPACETOP) {
        /* region overlaps the kernel. adjust the max length. */
        *stoplen = USERSPACETOP - bot;
    }

    return 0;
}

/*
 * copyin
 *
 * Copy a block of memory of length LEN from user-level address USERSRC
 * to kernel address DEST. We can use memcpy because it's protected by
 * the tm_badfaultfunc/copyfail logic.
 */
int
copyin(const_userptr_t usersrc, void *dest, size_t len)
{
    int result;
    size_t stoplen;

    result = copycheck(usersrc, len, &stoplen);
    if (result) {
        return result;
    }
    if (stoplen != len) {
        /* Single block, can't legally truncate it. */
        return EFAULT;
    }

    curthread->t_machdep.tm_badfaultfunc = copyfail;

    result = setjmp(curthread->t_machdep.tm_copyjmp);
    if (result) {
        curthread->t_machdep.tm_badfaultfunc = NULL;
        return EFAULT;
    }

    memcpy(dest, (const void *)usersrc, len);

    curthread->t_machdep.tm_badfaultfunc = NULL;
    return 0;
}

/*
 * copyout
 *
 * Copy a block of memory of length LEN from kernel address SRC to
 * user-level address USERDEST. We can use memcpy because it's
 * protected by the tm_badfaultfunc/copyfail logic.
 */
int
copyout(const void *src, userptr_t userdest, size_t len)
{
    int result;
    size_t stoplen;

    result = copycheck(userdest, len, &stoplen);
    if (result) {
        return result;
    }
    if (stoplen != len) {
        /* Single block, can't legally truncate it. */
        return EFAULT;
    }

    curthread->t_machdep.tm_badfaultfunc = copyfail;

    result = setjmp(curthread->t_machdep.tm_copyjmp);
    if (result) {
        curthread->t_machdep.tm_badfaultfunc = NULL;
        return EFAULT;
    }

    memcpy((void *)userdest, src, len);

    curthread->t_machdep.tm_badfaultfunc = NULL;
    return 0;
}

/*
 * Common string copying function that behaves the way that's desired
 * for copyinstr and copyoutstr.
 *
 * Copies a null-terminated string of maximum length MAXLEN from SRC
 * to DEST. If GOTLEN is not null, store the actual length found
 * there. Both lengths include the null-terminator. If the string
 * exceeds the available length, the call fails and returns
 * ENAMETOOLONG.
 *
 * STOPLEN is like MAXLEN but is assumed to have come from copycheck.
 * If we hit MAXLEN it's because the string is too long to fit; if we
 * hit STOPLEN it's because the string has run into the end of
 * userspace. Thus in the latter case we return EFAULT, not
 * ENAMETOOLONG.
 */
static
int
copystr(char *dest, const char *src, size_t maxlen, size_t stoplen,
    size_t *gotlen)
{
    size_t i;

    for (i=0; i<maxlen && i<stoplen; i++) {
        dest[i] = src[i];
        if (src[i] == 0) {
            if (gotlen != NULL) {
                *gotlen = i+1;
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
    if (stoplen < maxlen) {
        /* ran into user-kernel boundary */
        return EFAULT;
    }
    /* otherwise just ran out of space */
    return ENAMETOOLONG;
}

/*
 * copyinstr
 *
 * Copy a string from user-level address USERSRC to kernel address
 * DEST, as per copystr above. Uses the tm_badfaultfunc/copyfail
 * logic to protect against invalid addresses supplied by a user
 * process.
 */
int
copyinstr(const_userptr_t usersrc, char *dest, size_t len, size_t *actual)
{
    int result;
    size_t stoplen;

    result = copycheck(usersrc, len, &stoplen);
    if (result) {
        return result;
    }

    curthread->t_machdep.tm_badfaultfunc = copyfail;

    result = setjmp(curthread->t_machdep.tm_copyjmp);
    if (result) {
        curthread->t_machdep.tm_badfaultfunc = NULL;
        return EFAULT;
    }

    result = copystr(dest, (const char *)usersrc, len, stoplen, actual);

    curthread->t_machdep.tm_badfaultfunc = NULL;
    return result;
}

/*
 * copyoutstr
 *
 * Copy a string from kernel address SRC to user-level address
 * USERDEST, as per copystr above. Uses the tm_badfaultfunc/copyfail
 * logic to protect against invalid addresses supplied by a user
 * process.
 */
int
copyoutstr(const char *src, userptr_t userdest, size_t len, size_t *actual)
{
    int result;
    size_t stoplen;

    result = copycheck(userdest, len, &stoplen);
    if (result) {
        return result;
    }

    curthread->t_machdep.tm_badfaultfunc = copyfail;

    result = setjmp(curthread->t_machdep.tm_copyjmp);
    if (result) {
        curthread->t_machdep.tm_badfaultfunc = NULL;
        return EFAULT;
    }

    result = copystr((char *)userdest, src, len, stoplen, actual);

    curthread->t_machdep.tm_badfaultfunc = NULL;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You also need to look in the code at how/where it is used and not just it's definition.

Comment: @kaylum Right, I'm gonna add some examples. Thanks.

Comment: Looks to me it's a pointer that contains a user space address. Which means the kernel needs extra work to access it (via page mappings and not directly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a strong typedef, i.e. a typedef intended to increase type safety by avoiding unintended uses/conversions of the wrapped data.

In your context, most likely intended to differentiate kernel pointers from user space pointers (usually mapped via the MMU).